# multiple domains with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm having difficulties getting an htaccess to work with a subdomain.
**my server structure:**

`root / index.php`  ---//codeigniter index file, for application A, main domain points here.
`root/staging/StagingWebsite` ---// my subdomain is pointing here.
the folder StagingWebsite has a file called **temp.html**
moving on, my root htaccess file is this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond 
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Which turns any access to MyDomain/foo to MyDomain/index.php/foo. (without showing the index.php).

**The problem:**
When I try to access my `subdomain/temp.html`, I get a `500 internal error`.
when I remove my `root/.htaccess`, it works fine. So it's obviously my htaccess file.

I've figured out the problem is that the `root/.htaccess` rule is being applied to the subdomain, which breaks everything, But I have no ideahow to sort it out.

I've placed an empty .htaccess file inside the `root/staging/StagingWebsite` hoping it would just over-write any previous htaccess settings, But that didn't work.

**EDIT**
I fixed the issue specifically but I don't like the solution.
I added a RewriteCond to only run the rewrite rule for as specific domain.
Is there a way to solve this without specifying a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/root/staging/StagingWebsite/.htaccess` with this line only:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

This will overwrite any parent's rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any reason why an empty htaccess didn't work?

Comment: Yes empty .htaccess doesn't override rewrite rules from parent .htaccess but adding `RewriteEngine on` does the trick.